# How to execute Queries with multiple models in Entity framework with Dependency Injection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, entity-framework-4.1

I tried using Dependency Injection with Entity framework in my MVC application. In the project I have defined Generic Repository class for CRUD operations. There are concrete service classes for each model object. My Controller in Presentation layer uses Concrete classes of Service layer to get data from database. These concrete classes in turn calls RepositoryClass methods to implement actual operation with database.

Below is sample of the class definations (for simplicity I have removed various interfaces details and implementation of some methods):

```
class RepositoryBase<T>
{    
  Add(T entity) {...}
  Update (T entity) {...}    
  Delete (T entity) {...}   
  T GetById(int id) {...}     
  IEnumerable<T> GetAll() 
  {dbContext.ToList();} 
 }

 public class CarsService  {
    public IEnumerable<Cars> GetCars()
    {  
       var cars = RepositoryBase<Cars>.GetAll();
        return cars;  
    }
    public Car GetCar(int id)
    {            
       var car = RepositoryBase<T>.GetById(id);              
       return car;         
    }
  }

 Public class DealerService {...}
```

All this works great as long as I have to deal with 1 object type at a time in my application. But I am not sure how to make change in service class to get data for multiple entities i.e. Car and dealers togather. Please note in my scenario although i have dealer id defined in Cars model but navigation property is missing. So I have to join Cars and Dealers using linq query.

Please help to identify correct class (layer) which needs to be modified. All the examples I have found only talks about 1 entity at a time.

Comment: You need to use the unit of work pattern. EFs `ObjectContext` is a unit of work, or you can create an abstraction over it, [like this article shows](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=84).

Comment: Another [good article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff714955.aspx) on EF and the Unit of Work pattern.

Comment: I am using unit of work pattern in the application. I have not included in code here to make the question simple.

Answer (score 0):

DbContext.Set().Include()first of all you put you config mapping for fixing, 
second if you don't want to use navigation properties , you can use

```
RepositoryBase<Cars>.GetEntitySet<Cars>.Include("Dealers") //this does join if you key to join
```

but in this case you should use the 
add to `RepositoryBase<T>` a property

```
public ISet<T> GetEntitySet<T>(string table2Include)
{
   return DbContext.Set<T>()
}
```

Comment: What is method Include here? There is no such method in dbcontext class. Do I need to add this method and implementation in my DataContext class?

Comment: They are extension methods. Find them [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbextensions%28VS.103%29.aspx)